# HG: Update a directory to a specific revision without cloning the whole repo?

Tags: mercurial

Is it possible to `update` a directory to a specific revision without cloning the whole repository (local or on a central server) in Mercurial and how can I use it? This would be great, because to `clone` the whole repo first takes to much time for me and the folder really don't needs the whole repo. As example: *default* and the *b2.3* branch from which I want to update.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Perhaps you have combined independent projects in a single repository? This is common practice with Subversion, but distributed revision control systems are different. Also, what you're really asking is how to make a "narrow" or "partial" clone, a concept which we do not yet support. There is a wiki page here: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PartialClone

Comment: yes, we switched from svn to hg :)
maybie we should just divide the projects into repositorys, but they have dependencies on each other.

because a normal clone is time- and size?-consuming and the repo already is local (why to have it on two places) a partical clone [e.g. hg clone -p or --partial] would be perhaps great (or if there is an easy workaround for getting it fast and with version history)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pull a specific branch, say `b2.3` by using `hg clone -r b2.3 source-repo target-repo`.

If you really need just a non-versioned copy of all the files in revision N, then for some web repositories you may download such a copy using their web interface.

Answer (score 1):

`clone` is the preferred way to do it in Mercurial.  It should take a minimal amount of time when done locally.  I'm unaware of any other way to do it.

Search for "hard links" on [this tutorial page](http://hginit.com/03.html) for more info on the subject.

Comment: @Joschua: remember that you only need to do the full clone once. When you have all the history on your machine, then you can do 'hg clone -r b2.3 foo bar' to make a quick clone with only some of the history. The key point is that you don't have to contact the server again for the changesets you already have locally.